# Deserialization of JSON containing reserved keywords

Tags: scala, apache-spark, json4s

I have a JSON string that looks like the following,

```
{ "name": "foo", "type": "mytype1" }
```

This is part of a complex JSON and I don't have control over the JSON. I am trying to extract it into a case class, which isn't possible because "type" is a reserved keyword.

In C#, I would be doing the following,

```
[JsonProperty(Name = "blah")]
public string SomethingElse { get; set; }
```

Is there an equivalent of that construct in json4s ?

Comment: BEWARE: Json4s is [vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial)!

Answer (score 2):

Note that you can use reserved keywords by enclosing them in backticks:

```
case class Foo(name: String, `type`: String)

val x: Foo = ???
println(x.`type`)
```

Accessing the `type` member is a little cumbersome, so if you'd rather have something like:

```
case class Foo(name: String, typ: String)
```

You can define a custom serializer like so:

```
object Foo {
  val jsonSerializer = new CustomSerializer[Foo](format => ({
      case JObject(JField("name", JString(name)) :: JField("type", JString(typ)) :: Nil) => Foo(name = name, typ = typ)
    },
    {
      case foo: Foo => JObject(JField("name", JString(foo.name)) :: JField("type", JString(foo.typ)) :: Nil)
    }))
}
```